# Can malware access my passwords? How do I keep my accounts safe if they did?

Tags: security, passwords, malware, dashlane

I've already decided I have some sort of Malware, but I want to know what information is at risk. I've changed a few passwords since the problem started, and I've had a lot of other online activity. I have a program called Dashlane that's supposed to keep my passwords safe, and it has all of my passwords from my Chrome browser on it.

Is someone able to access my accounts using the Malware to find my passwords?

If so, how can I fix the problem?

Another thing is that it would be really hard for me to spend a lot of time fixing my computer right now, because I need it for school, is there a quick way I can fix it until I have time to make a more extensive fix?

**Proof that this question is unique:**

- In this question, I am asking whether they can find my passwords using Dashlane, and my password changes.
- In this question I am asking how I can keep my accounts safe, even if they have stolen my passwords using malware.
- The answer at [this site](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) didn't explain how to keep your accounts safe after they have already stolen passwords, or whether Malware can steal passwords from programs like Dashlane.

Comment: After you remove the malware, change your passwords. Any other advice would require a complete understanding of the specific malware, or if you had specific viruses also, if they included keyloggers, if they sent data over the web etc.

Comment: " I am asking whether they can find my passwords using Dashlane, and my password changes." - how can we possibly answer when we don't know what the malware is? At best we would be guessing. The only **safe** answer is to assume your passwords are all compromised.

Comment: Nuke the computer from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impractical to the extreme to steal passwords while they are encrypted unless the malware has been given the key.

The problem is that without knowing more about the malware, it *is* possible it has watched you type the key or stolen the key/passwords while they were unprotected in memory.

Fix #1:  You could scan your computer with as many legitimate scanners as you can get your hands on (RKill, RogueKiller, MalwareBytes AntiMalware, MalwareBytes AntiRootkit, TDSS Killer, Junkware Removal Tool, Panda Cloud Cleaner Portable, etc.).  These could take care of the infection.  You will also need to change all your passwords.

Fix #2:  A temporary (maybe you'll prefer it, though) workaround:  Install puppy linux on a flash drive, boot from it, and you have a working computer from which you have internet capability and probably have full access to the files stored on your HDD.  You'll still want to change all your passwords.

Fix #3, the nuclear option:  A more thorough fix (and sometimes faster than fix #1) is to wipe your drive, reinstall your OS, and change all passwords.

This reply assumes the second-worst.  The worst would be that everything has already been hacked and all your accounts are already out of your control.  The second worst is the assumption that complete compromise of your machine is true and your passwords are sitting in someone's database.  Neither scenario is necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your malware and its capabilities which can be checked based on its name (in the anti-virus database, e.g. upload the file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)), executing it in the simulated environment or by analysing the files (e.g. which system functions it's uses, which ports it opens and where does it send the captured data).

If malware is able to do [keystroke logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging) and transmit to the external destination, whatever you typed, it's already compromised. Especially when you typed your master password and malware copied also the relevant files of your password manager where all your passwords are stored. If you have enabled in Dashlane *Sync* option in *Preferences*, it doesn't need your files, your e-mail or username with your master password is enough to sync back your data anywhere else.

Some other feature that can be implemented to malware is to read or dump information about your processes, windows and its content (either by manual or automatic process). So if particular malware has logic which gives particular interest to *Dashlane* running process (or any other on the list), it can dump its content or memory dump and access depending whether it's encrypted or not. To find out, please read this [security analysis of Dashlane](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2016/files/25.pdf) (and [other](http://devd.me/papers/pwdmgr-usenix14.pdf)). See also: [Security analysis of Dashlane](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/74656/11825) at Security.SE.

If you think your Dashlane password has been compromised, you can always change your master password, then you can use [Password Changer feature](https://superuser.com/a/1257586/87805) which can change several passwords on different websites in a single click.

To be on the safe side, use real-time anti-virus, don't use external apps from non-reliable sources and keep your *Dashlane* app open to minimum.